# Simplify doesn't simplify Sign[d + f (a - b c)] to 1

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
Simplify[Sign[d + f (a - b c)], {f > 0, d > 0, a > b c, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> Sign[d + f (a - b c)]

which should have been `1`. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4):

```
Reduce[{y == Sign[d + f (a - b c)], f > 0, d > 0, a > b c, a > 0, 
  b > 0, c > 0}, y, {a, b, c, d, f}, Reals]

FunctionRange[{Sign[d + f (a - b c)], f > 0, d > 0, a > b c, a > 0, 
  b > 0, c > 0}, {a, b, c, d, f}, y]

PiecewiseExpand[Sign[d+f (a-b c)],Reals,
  Method->{"ConditionSimplifier"->(Reduce[{#,f>0,d>0,a>b c,a>0,b>0,c>0}]&)}]

With[{assum = And[f > 0, d > 0, a > b c, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0]}, 
 Simplify[Sign[d + f (a - b c)], assum, 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Reduce[# && assum, {}, {a, b, c, d, f}] &}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, do you agree it is a bug?